# Работа с UTF-8 строками средствами Windows API

Tags: c, winapi

Вопрос следующий. Моя программа должна принимать в качестве аргументов командной строки строку с кириллицей. При этом строка может быть как в ASCII, OEM, так и в UTF-8. Очень не хочется пользоваться внешними либами. Как мне просчитать средствами WinAPI необходимый буфер для wchar_t* для argv[1], если аргумент задан строкой в кодировке UTF-8?

C++ не использую, только чистый Си.

Comment: С чего вы взяли что данные будут переданы в utf8? Кстати utf8 использует суррогатные пары а не широкие символы.

Comment: @ori , ну если я их укажу в пакетном файле в UTF-8, они будут как-то преобразовываться без моего ведома? Кстати ... на счет кодирования UTF-8 я в курсе, полностью)) Поэтому, собственно, и задал вопрос UTF8->UTF16.

Comment: Тогда https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Следует принимать на вход сразу строки wchar_t. В ASCII и OEM кириллицу передать не получится.

Comment: в аски не получится, но вот с ОЕМ - тут спорный вопрос. в случае windows oem и cp866 могут быть синонимами.